# React hooks - useEffect exhaustive deps - cyclic dependency on location.hash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a `useEffect` which reads the `location.hash` and based on some other dependencies, will change the hash. It looks something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const hashAlreadyPresent = () => {
      const hashArr = history.location.hash.split('#');
      return hashArr.includes(hashId);
    };

    const addToHash = () => {
      return history.location.hash.concat(`#${hashId}`);
    };

    const removeFromHash = () => {
      const hashArray = history.location.hash.split('#').filter(hashStr => hashStr);
      const indexOfHashId = hashArray.indexOf(hashId);
      (indexOfHashId !== -1) && hashArray.splice(indexOfHashId, 1);

      return hashArray;
    };

    // if hashId props is present then attach hash in route
    hashId && !hashAlreadyPresent() && history.push({
      hash: `${hashAlreadyPresent() ? '' : addToHash()}`,
      search: history.location.search,
    });

    return () => {
      // remove hashId only, retain any other hash if present
      const hashArray = removeFromHash();
      hashId && hashAlreadyPresent() && history.replace({
        hash: hashArray.join('#'),
        search: history.location.search,
      });
    };
  }, [history, hashId, history.location.hash, history.location.search]);
```

where `history` is from React Router.

The logic is that once the component is on screen (mounted), it adds a hash to the URL and once it is getting unmounted it will remove the hash from the url.

Of course, in terms of useEffect it translates to: if any of the dependencies change, the previous effect would be cleaned up and a new instance of the effect would be in place. The effective deps rule helped me with that, as earlier i was missing the fact that this hook should be cleaned up and re-run if `hashId` changes.

Now, we should have a dependency on `history.location.hash` for exhaustive deps, but the problem is every time I change `hash` from within the hook, the hook will run again (the previous instance will cleanup and change the `hash` again), which would lead to an infinite update kind of scenario.

NOTE: I know this is possible by switching off exhaustive-deps rule and excluding `history.location.hash` from dependencies, but would like to figure out any possibilities of refactoring/breaking down the `useEffect`, so that this can be solved without turning it off.

Another thing to note is that if I add `history` as a dependency (Which I have to because i am using a method from `history`), then the rule does not ask me to explicitly add the nested dependecies (`history.lcoation.search`, `history.location.hash`), but, those should be added, as the `history` object would remain the same but the nested objects would change on url change. This is same as the use case where you specify complete `props` object as a dependency instead of only the required specific nested properties.

Should i have a condition inside my useEffect based on when the location changes, which can somehow tell me if the location was changed from inside the hook and so don't do anything ?

Should i destructure and specify the dependencies in a different way, so that the effect does not run when the location.hash is changed from within the effect ?

**NOTE:**
had a discussion for this on github. got some more insights.
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19636

Answer (score 1):

When a non-empty dependency array is specified, any value that you add to the dependency array causes the cleanup function to run first (except on the first render), followed by the effect function (except during unmount). To decide whether a value should go into the dependency array then, try answering this question for that value:

When this value is updated, should the effect run again, such that:

- The desired effect is observed
- Any potential changes made previously are cleaned up if required
- No bugs due to stale references are introduced?

If the answer is yes for any of the points above, then that value makes it to the dependency array.

We can now answer the question above for all the values used within the `useEffect` function:

- `hashId`: **Yes**. This is the primary driver for the effect, and each time this value changes, the URL should reflect the change. This becomes the source of truth for the effect. Therefore this is required to ensure that the desired effect is observed. Additionally, this is also required to clean up the previous `hashId` as the clean up function needs a reference to the previous `hashId`.
- `history`: **Yes**. I suppose that as this is provided by react router, the reference should not change throughout the component's life cycle. In that sense, the only purpose of adding it here would be to satisfy the lint rule, with no real impact (other than an extra referential check). However, if it *does* change, the effect function will have a stale reference to it which could potentially cause bugs. This has to be taken care of.
- `history.location.search`: **No**. This has nothing to do with the primary effect, as only the `hashId` is required to ensure that the desired effect is observed. There is also no danger of stale references, as this is always read from the `history` object. Since the `history` object is mutable and updated with the latest value every time, and is already a part of the dependency array, `history.location.search` can be safely omitted. *
- `history.location.hash`: **No**, for the same arguments as for `history.location.search`. Additionally, it is always `hashId` that determines what the `history.location.hash` should be, so an update to this value should not be used to re-run the effect.

The final dependency array then is just `[hashId, history]`. **

---

** be careful to not extract out `search` from `history.location` and use `search` within the cleanup function, as it will be a stale reference*

*** noticed `routeModal` being used in the body of the effect, if needed this would also have to be a part of the dependency array*

Comment: have removed the routeModal thing, it was a typo

Comment: if let's say i remove `history.push`/`history.replace` code from the useEffect, the lint rule will start complaining that `history.location.hash` should be a dependency, so I don't think that removing `history.location.search` should satisfy the exhaustive deps, although in this case it would work, as in, the rule would not complain, because the parent object history is already specified in dependenices. But we know that is wrong, similar to how we can have props object as dependency instead of the nested properties, which is incorrect

Comment: also, generallly speaking, there might be a case where my component needs to attach itself to the url once again if user manually changes the url while this component is mounted, for e.g, user removes this hash and adds another hash to the url, then the component is still mounted but the hash has been removed, in which case, the correct state might be to re-add the hash

Comment: If the user manually changes the hash, the effect above has no way to handle that. It will be called only when the component using the effect updates.

If you want complete control over the text after the hash, I think you should be maintaining this desired hash string in a `ref`, updating the `ref` as `hashId` changes using an effect. You can then have additional effects that use the `ref` to update the URL as per the components and also by subscribing to the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) events, to handle user URL modification.

Comment: if the user manually changes the hash in the address bar, react router would re-render this component